# Opera 18 Web developer tools

Tags: opera

How can I detach the developer tools window in Opera 18 to be in separate window. I try with the button Detach, but instead going in single window, will dock on the right side. Either goes in the right side ot on the bottom....cannot make it separate window.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a [] looking button at the bottom left of the web inspector that will detach/attach it to the main window.

Comment: doesn't seems to help. I press that button but the tool window is docked on the right side. It is not on the bottom, it is on the right side, but still docked, not in separate window